# why gzwrite vector is diffent from gzwrite array with the array value is same?

Tags: c++, gzip

I put the same values in different container(vector and array) and gzwrite them by zlib lib,but the result is diffent.

function gzwrite to write unsigned char[] into gz file

```
gzFile fi = gzopen(geopath, "wb");
unsigned char a[]= { 'n','h','h' };
vector<unsigned char> b({ 'n','h','h' });
gzwrite(fi, a, size(a));
//gzwrite(fi,&b, size(b));
gzclose(fi);
```

write array the output is that 6E6868(Expected result)
write vector the output is that 00AF27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vector<unsigned char> b({ 'n','h','h' });
gzwrite(fi,&b, size(b));
```

Here you take a pointer to the whole `b` variable, which contains the internal size and capacity fields of `std::vector`.

Use `gzwrite(fi, b.data(), size(b));` instead.